# TreeGraph construction

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, trees

I have a list `l={{1,1},{2,3},{2,3,2,3,4}}`. Based on that list, I want to draw a tree. Starting from a single point at the top of a tree, I proceed as follows, using the list: 
first we draw two single branches from the first point (that's what `{1,1}` tells us). Then  `{2,3}` tells us that we go back to the point at the end of the first of the new branches and draw 2 new branches, similarly, from the second new branch, i.e. new point, we draw 3 new branches. So at this point, on the lowest level, we already have 5 points. Then, `{2,3,2,3,4}` tells us how many branches we draw from each of these points, from left to right. So we would end up with a tree:

[image]

Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update 2:** Relabeling vertices using `VertexReplace`:

```
With[{gr1 = SetProperty[g @ l1, VertexLabels -> "Name"]}, 
 VertexReplace[gr1, 
  Thread[SortBy[VertexList[gr1], Length@VertexComponent[gr1, #] &] -> VertexList[gr1]]]]
```

[image]

You can also use `BreadthFirstScan` as suggested by @Szabolcs's in the comments to relabel the vertices:

```
relabel = Module[{vl = Thread[First@Last@ Reap @ BreadthFirstScan[#, 1, 
      {"PrevisitVertex" -> Sow}] -> VertexList[#]]},
    SetProperty[#, VertexLabels -> vl]] &;

Row[SetProperty[relabel @ #, ImageSize -> 600] & /@ {g @ l1, g @ l4}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[g]
g = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[
    Map[ConstantArray[x, #] &, 
     Fold[TakeList, Last[#], Reverse[Rest@Most@#]], {-1}], 
    VertexLabels -> None] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
l1 =  {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 4}};
g @ l1
```

[image]

```
l2 = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}};
g @ l2
```

[image]

```
l3 = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}};
g @ l3
```

[image]

```
l4 = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
g @ l4
```

[image]

```
l5 = NestList[PadRight[#, 2 Length @ #, "Periodic"]&, {1, 3, 2}, 5];
SetProperty[UndirectedGraph[g @ l5], {ImageSize -> Large, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"}]
```

[image]

**Update:**  You can also use `TreeForm` instead of `` GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph ``:

```
tf = TreeForm[
    Map[ConstantArray[x, #] &, 
     Fold[TakeList, Last[#], Reverse[Rest@Most@#]], {-1}], 
    VertexLabeling -> False] &;

tf @ l1
```

[image]

Comment: That is amazing! thank you so much!

Comment: is there a way of changing the index of vertices without interfering with a tree , for your function `g`? So that they're numbered row by row, i.e. `{{1},{2,3},{4,5,6,7,8},...}` ?

Comment: @amator2357 Instead of the undocumented ``GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph``, which may change unexpectedly in future versions, you can use `IGExpressionTree` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM). I was going to post an answer with it, but I see that kglr used the same principle.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for that suggestion. The indexing still has to be modified, I'm not even sure if it's possible. Perhaps, I'd have come up with a different way of writing the expression which I pass to `IGExpressionTree`. Anyway, what a nice package that is.

Comment: @amator2357 What you seem to want is breadth first order. You could obtain the list of vertices in this order using `First@Last@BreadthFirstScan[graph, root, {"PrevisitVertex"->Sow]` or similar. You need to give the root vertex manually.  Then you rebuild the graph as `Graph[vertices, edges]` then finally apply `IndexGraph` to rename vertices to their integer index. The problem is that `IGExpressionTree` uses lists as vertex names, including `{}`. `{}` is not accepted as the root vertex by `BreadthFirstSearch` (this is a bug in Mathematica). ...

Comment: @amator2357 ... Thus you need to apply `IndexGraph` _before_ you do anything else to avoid the problem with `{}`.  With ``GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph``, the root vertex is always 1 and vertices are always named as integers. So you can use the method above to creating the breadth first order.

Comment: @amator2357 The thing is that re-labelling vertices according to your request could be considered a separate issue. If you ask a dedicated question, kglr or I will post a full answert.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for that explanation. For my case, since I always start from one vertex at the top, I've managed to achieve what  I wanted. It is rather basic, but it works for my case. For more general use, it'd require some modification(s). I'll post it here later, maybe it'd be of some sort educational value for someone at some point.

Comment: @Szabolcs, It would be a good idea  to post a solution using `IGExpressionTree` (I am back to version 9, so could not use `IGraph/M`).

Comment: @amator2357, posted an update to relabel the vertices using Szabolcs's suggestion.

Comment: @kglr thank you for that update! So many things I've learnt from yours  and Szabolcs's answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way using the [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Before we start I wanted to note that it seems to me that to be consistent, the first element of your list should be `{2}` and not `{1,1}`. Each list element has the number of children for each node at each level. At the first level there is *one* node with two children, i.e. `{2}`, and not two nodes with one child each.

`IGExpressionTree` will convert an expression to the `Graph` in a way similar to `TreeForm`.  The actual names of nodes will be the same as their [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) in the input expression. These positions look ugly, but I will use them for labelling below, to make it clear what is happening.

```
l={{1,1},{2,3},{2,3,2,3,4}}

tree =
 IGExpressionTree[
  Fold[TakeList, ConstantArray[1, Total@Last[l]], Most@Reverse[l]],
  VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphStyle -> "CoolColor"
 ]
```

[image]

The expression this originated from is

```
Fold[TakeList, ConstantArray[1, Total@Last[l]], Most@Reverse[l]]
(* {{{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}} *)
```

Now we need to rename the vertices using integers that come in breadth-first order. Notice that with the existing vertex names, it is sufficient to sort the vertex list to put it in breadth-first order.  When sorting, Mathematica considers shorter lists to come before longer ones. Lists of the same length come in lexicographic order.

```
Sort@VertexList[tree]
(* {{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 
  1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1,
   2}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 
  3}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```

We re-order the vertices like so using `IGReorderVertices` and then rename them to their integer index using `IndexGraph`.

```
IndexGraph@IGReorderVertices[Sort@VertexList[tree], tree]
```

[image]

The flashy CoolColor style is just for better readability of labels that overlap with edges.

---

As a bonus, here's a way to convert the output of `IGExpressionTree` back to the representation you started with.

```
VertexList[tree] // GroupBy[Length] // KeySort // Rest // 
    Map@GroupBy[Most] // Map@Map[Length] // Values // Values
(* {{2}, {2, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

This is relatively easy because the vertices of the tree are named naturally and already encode the tree structure.

I always wished that some of the built-in graph generators would return natural vertex names.  Maple makes extensive use of natural naming, and takes full advantage of the ability to use any expression for vertices.

Here's what a grid graph looks like in Maple and Mathematica:

[image]
[image]

There are many missed opportunities here such as `DeBruijnGraph`, which could be labelled [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph#/media/File:DeBruijn-as-line-digraph.svg).

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your answer. This is such a nice and clear explanation, very useful. Perhaps MathematicaSE should have an option of accepting more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will post my own answer as well, just for completeness.  @kglr's and @Szabolcs's  answers are much nicer, and work for more general cases, but in my situation, I needed something slightly different, as explained in the comments.

```
l={{1,1},{2,3},{2,3,2,3,4}}

labels1 = TakeList[Table[i,{i,4,Total@Flatten@l + 1}],Flatten@Drop[#,1]& @ l];

Index = Table[,{i,1,Total@Flatten@l }];
Index[[1]] = 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2;
Index[[2]] = 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3;

labels2 = Flatten@Table[DirectedEdge[i+1,#]& /@ labels1[[i]],{i,1,Length[labels1]}];

Table[Index[[i]]= labels2[[i-2]],{i,3,Length[labels2]+2}];
Index;

TreeGraph[#,VertexLabels->"Index"]& @ Index
```

[image]

Below  is what I needed it for:[image]

**Update:** Both @kglr's and @Szabolc's answers do exactly what I needed now, in a much neater way.